# Data validation for combo box range of column using EPPlus

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, epplus

I using EPplus for exporting excel.i have to give a combo box.Currently i have given the range manually.but i want this dropdown for entire column.Can any one tell how to do this

```
ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage();
 ExcelWorksheet P = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Pass");

 var droplist = P.DataValidations.AddListValidation("C2:C50000");   
 droplist.Formula.Values.Add("a");
 droplist.Formula.Values.Add("b");
```

Comment: Edit your question and post a more meaningful heading. Something like: *Add data validation to an entire column in Excel using EPPlus*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line should work:

```
var droplist = P.DataValidations.AddListValidation("C:C");
```

**EDIT:**

Alternatively, you can set `ExcelRange` to `MaxRows`. You can then define the range then skipping the first or first n rows. Code below skips first row:

```
var range = ExcelRange.GetAddress(2, 3, ExcelPackage.MaxRows, 3);
var val = p.DataValidations.AddListValidation(excelRange);
```

Where `GetAddress` is:

```
public static string GetAddress(int FromRow, int FromColumn, int ToRow, int ToColumn)
```

[ExcelCellBase](http://epplus.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#EPPlus/ExcelCellBase.cs) has the extension method to get an address: `GetAddress`

[ExcelPackage](http://epplus.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#EPPlus/ExcelPackage.cs) has a public const `MaxRows` *(1048576)*

Comment: thank you very much.is it possible to hide first cell in c column.since it is heading